# Trying to find the area of a black space of a circles that hold squares inside of them

Tags: geometry

Find the area of a black space of a circles that hold squares inside of them.

[image]

The problem in German, but it's basically asking the same thing I wrote above. It also gives the radius of the biggest circle which is 1, so in other words this is a unit circle.

Edit: So I just realized that I totally forgot to mention what I know about this problem, so the way that I know is to take r and multiply it by 2 to find the side of the first square by using the Pythagorean theorem, and then just go from there to find the next circle radius by dividing the length of the first side by 2. After all of that is done then am gonna be able to find out all the areas of circles and squares, then I just add the circles areas together and then subtract  from them the sum of the squares areas, the final answer came out to be around 1.99, however this way of solving takes a lot of time and this problem is found on an admition test meaning that it should be solved in less than 4 minutes. My question is, is there any other way of doing it, perhaps a quicker more logical way. Thanks in advance for all the replies.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Hint: the diagonal of inscribed square is also the diameter of the circle.

Comment: It seems to be a sum of a geometric (or square) area.

Comment: The shaded areas within the inner circles are proportional to the shaded area outside of the largest square.

Comment: It can hardly be simper than $(\pi-2)(1+1/2+1/4)$.

Comment: So User, could you please explain more on how you got this answer (π−2)(1+1/2+1/4), it seems like it is going to be much faster than my way. And Daniel I knew that there was some ratios going on, I just couldn't figure them out, perhaps you can please elaborate more. Thanks in advance for all the replies.